# Custom session manager in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

Where can I find documentation on creating a custom session manager for Tomcat?

For example:

How do I configure my session manager in tomcats server.xml?
What interface must be implemented to use my session manager?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Q:** How do I configure my session manager in tomcats server.xml ?
**A:** [`<Manager...`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/manager.html) goes inside [`<Context...`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html). From Tomcat docs:

> A Manager element MAY be nested inside a Context component. If it is
>   not included, a default Manager configuration will be created
>   automatically, which is sufficient for most requirements, — see
>   Standard Manager Implementation below for the details of this
>   configuration.

**Q:** What interface must be implemented to use my session manager ?
**A:** [`org.apache.catalina.Manager`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/Manager.html)

Comment: How do I specify the default Manager for ALL Contexts ? i.e. directly on server.xml, without specifying a Context component or context.xml ?

Comment: Found it, edit `conf/context.xml` ! Yay! :) -- This should've been better mentioned in the Tomcat docs

Comment: FYI uncommenting the manager in context.xml will disable session replication across tomcat nodes