# Is it a good idea to set session time out to be very short for rest ws?

Tags: rest, jersey

I understand that rest ws is stateless. And we are expecting pretty high traffic. Is it a good idea to set session timeout (we are using tomcat) really low? Like one minute? pros and cons?

Comment: As you mentioned yourself, REST is stateless. What need do you have for a session and why such a short lived one?

Comment: Well, we are using Jersey as WS container and deployed in tomcat. Is it true if I don't call request.getSession() or request.getSession(true) , the session won't be persisted by tomcat. If that is the case, I shouldn't worry about the setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are expecting high traffic, session management will bring overhead to your application and with a one minute timeout your server will consume time invalidating lots of sessions.

If your application is indeed stateless then don't use sessions. [You can't fully disable them either but if you don't do `getSession()` then you should be fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255814/can-i-turn-off-the-httpsession-in-web-xml).

If you (absolutely) want to be sure no code is creating sessions, you could have a look at Tomcat's session [manager component](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/manager.html) and maybe create your [own implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683493/custom-session-manager-in-tomcat) that tells you what's happening when you subject your server to some [stress tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_testing_%28software%29).